# Cannot save CIImage to camera roll - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, swift3

I'm trying to apply a filter to a CIImage, which was created from a pixel buffer from an AVCaptureSession and then save it to the camera roll.

Here's my code

```
        let image = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)

        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
        filter?.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter?.setValue(0.1, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)

        let newImage = UIImage(ciImage: (filter?.outputImage)!)

        print ("new image: \(newImage)")

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, self,    #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
```

This throws no errors, and when image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:) is called it has not error

But the image does not appear in my library. Very confusing! Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ask for writing permissions?

Comment: yes writing permissions are OK and I've managed to write already from a normal uiimage.

Comment: Try breaking down the line of code that creates the filtered CIImage (and does a force unwrap along with turning it into a UIImage) into individual lines. See if you are actually getting any output from the filter. Also, see what the image image looks like. CIfilters will not always yield an error if they are set up correctly, but instead give you worthless output.

Answer (score 8):

I've also faced this problem with same situation and solved it.

My method is: first convert it to CGImage, then convert the CGImage object to UIImage, in this case can you succeed to save the processed image to camera roll.

Here is the code.

```
let input = CIImage(image: MyImageView.image!)
let filter = PinkyFilter() // My custom filter
filter.setValue(input, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
let context = CIContext() // Prepare for create CGImage
let cgimg = context.createCGImage(filter.outputImage, from: filter.outputImage.extent)
let output = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
```

Then the output is a save-able object.

Comment: This answer saved my life! Thanks!

Comment: can you just create UIImage from CIImage using UIImage(ciImage: ..))?

Comment: @alenLiang Using UIImage from CIImage causes a random failure in the photo library saving code. I get a 3303 error in the domain PHPhotosErrorDomain. Using the CGImage workaround fixes the issue.